# Div:hover моргает за пределами границ

Tags: css, hover

Для `div:hover` я задаю `width: 25%`, но когда курсор стоит за пределами `div`'a начинается моргание. Как это иcправить?

Answer (score 0):

`width: 25%` этот `hover` взаимодействует с другим элементом разметки - используйте     `z-index: 1;` и `z-index: 0`

Answer (score 0):

- можно использовать дополнительную обертку для div
- если я правильно понял что тебе нужно то получается так.

```css
.wrap, .test{
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
}

.test {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.wrap:hover  div {
  width: 25%;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="test">Уменьшается при наведении</div>
</div>
```

- либо вариант через :before без доп обертки

```css
.test{
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
}

.test:before {
content: "";
display: block;
background-color: #2980b9;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.test:hover:before {
width: 25%;
transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
  <div class="test"></div>
```